# Trigger TeamCity build with build parameters in HTTP URI

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-9.0, teamcity-8.0, teamcity-7.0

I have the following build config for TeamCity (in XML):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<build>
  <buildType id="my_build_config_id"/>
  <comment>
    <text>mybuild</text>
  </comment>
  <properties>
    <property name="env.PARAM1" value="abc"/>
    <property name="env.PARAM2" value="xyz"/>
    <property name="env.PARAM3" value="123"/>
  </properties>
</build>
```

I'm able to trigger a build with their REST API [as documented](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/rest-api-reference.html#Triggering+a+Build) with this XML config:

```
curl -v -u myuser:mypass http://teamcity.url:8111/app/rest/buildQueue --request POST --header "Content-Type:application/xml" --data-binary @build.xml
```

However, I want to encode all of my build parameters inside the URI itself. it doesn't seem clearly documented how to trigger the same build with all of the XML encoded as URI parameters. Reading between the lines, it would look something like this:

```
curl -v -u  http://teamcity.url:8111/httpAuth/app/rest/buildQueue?buildType(id:my_build_config_id),comment(text:mybuild),properties(property:((name:env.PARAM1,value:abc),(name:env.PARAM2,value:xyz),(name:env.PARAM2,value:123))) --request POST
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Why do you conclude this is at all possible? As far as I can see, the docs do not mention that. This is a `POST` request which expects a `body` to be in place. What's the initial problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Oh good point, I think this was a GET request on an older version of the API with a `xml` parameter so I presumed there was some backward compatibility. :/